# SixenseInput prefab cause unity to crash

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have unity 4.5 and added Sixense package to it.
My scene includes: Sixense hands prefab and Sixense input prefab.
the sixense input prefab has a script called SixenseInput.cs which came with the Sixense package. 
The problem is when I start the scene everything works but when I stop the scene and start again unity is crashing and the log says - Access Violation.
I disabled the SixensInput script from the inspector and then Unity is never crashes. What can I do?!

Comment: Right now your question is asked in such a way that only someone familiar with this package could theoretically answer it. It might be a good idea to give more information for other developers — that would make your chances of getting an answer higher.

Comment: Yes but the package is from unity asset store.. I didn't write the code for it :) Do you want the error log?

Comment: I'm not saying that your question is bad in any way; I'm just suggesting that there aren't many developers answering Unity 3d questions here, and even fewer of them might know this particular package. I'd like to help you, but with this amount of information I wouldn't even know where to start.

Comment: Have you tried the same, but without a prefab, with just a gameObject that contains this script?

Comment: Have you tried the same in the scene completely empty except for empty object with this script?

Comment: Thanks golerka :) i will try your suggestion. It's really annoying to open Unity again and again..

Comment: Also, did you try it with Unity 5? ;)

Comment: So it also crashes with an empty game object - the SixenseInput script is the cause for the problem.. Oh, and I don't have Unity 5 :( Its exepensive

Comment: It's free. It has just been released yesterday, for free if you don't have (or earned) $100k for your project. Worth at least checking it out

Comment: I would probably suggest just deleting this QA, @Elior

Answer (score 1):

I also found the "SixenseUnityPlugin" asset to be sensitive to repeated stop and start of the Unity editor. The cause appeared to be a crash in the bundled native DLL.

The fix for me was to add the following to the file **SixenseInput.cs**:

```
public static bool isAlreadyQuited = false;

/// <summary>
/// Exit sixense when the application quits.
/// </summary>
void OnApplicationQuit()
{
    if (!isAlreadyQuited)
    {
        isAlreadyQuited = true;
        SixensePlugin.sixenseExit();
    }
}
```

I cannot recall wheter the used function "sixenseExit()" from **SixensePlugin.cs** was already present before, but this are the necessary lines there:

```
[DllImport("sixense", EntryPoint = "sixenseExit")]
public static extern int sixenseExit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something with the Sixense files was wrong. 
I uninstalled the Sixense asset from Unity - and then I downloaded and re-install
it.